# Why does my control extending RichTextBox defaults to gray background?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to extend a RichTextBox, so as to add some extra functionality; however, I'm running into a strange issue with the background color of my extended RTB.  Here is the code:

RichTextBoxExtended.cs

```
public class RichTextBoxExtended: RichTextBox
{
    // completely empty
}
```

MyView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBoxExtended />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

However, when showing this in a WPF page, the background color of the text box is gray, as if it were disabled (which it isn't, since I can still type into it fine). As a test, I replaced `<RichTextBoxExtended />` in the XAML with `<RichTextBox />`, and that control is white as expected.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue?  I can easily work around the problem by manually setting the background color to white, but am looking for a better solution.

Comment: It's working here....can you show where you are using the UserControl...show the XAML please.

Comment: I am not having that problem at all.

Comment: Try using Snoop - The wpf spy utility to inspect the issue - http://www.snoopwpf.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy paste your code to a test solution, place a frame in main window and put the `RichTextBoxExtended` in a page inside the frame, but the background of RTB is completely white. I think there is something else causing the problem.